# Form/UX design for mobile web & phonegap

Tags: html, ios, css, forms, cordova

I build PhoneGap apps that occasionally contain input forms. Such as textfields & textarea's.
However they always seem sluggish and buggy compared to for example native platform text inputs.

For example: if a text input is at the bottom of a div that uses `overflow: auto;` plus `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`, mobile browsers tend to open the keyboard and leave the div at the top. The input is now defocused and out of view. I would actually expect the browser to scroll the contents of the div all the way up so I can start typing instantly. This is happening on both Android & iOS.

Are there any best practices for forms with mobile browsers in mind?